# Can design patterns ruin abstraction?

Tags: c++, mysql, database, design-patterns

This is a theory question not a practical one.

I'm trying to design a program that follows software best practices. But I am having trouble figuring out the best way to do certain things that allow for Test Driven Development and good Encapsulation and Abstraction while also minimizing coupling.

I planed to have two layers of abstraction, a database management layer, and a table management layer.

```
class TableManager() 
{
    init() {
     manager = DatabaseManger()
    }

    do_operation(String operation) {
        connection = manager.get_db_connection()
        connection.execute(operation)
    } 
}
```

This seemed like a good idea because the actual connection details are hidden from the table manager. But it also seems bad because the TableManager is highly coupled to the DatabaseManager and for testing, I would need to have a separate database connection to set up the database state, things like drop the database and table so we test operations when the database does not exist and things like that

Can someone weigh in here and challenge my assumptions? I might be overestimating the importance of some factors or underestimating others. Is this a common problem with a design patter?

Comment: I think there isn't any other way then having a abstract table manager which is suited for each database.

Comment: Well, you could pass `manager` as a constructor argument to `TableManager`, and have a `MockDatabaseManager` which you can use for testing.

Comment: That is actually not that far off. I have two tables that each have their specific table manager and have their own DBManager. Would it make more sense to have the DBConnector be a separate object and pass in the connection as an argument?

Comment: A TableManager could depend on an `IDataBaseManager` instead, which is an interface that any DataBaseManager needs to implement. The `manager` instance could be passed into the `TableManager` upon construction, and now you've decoupled them.

Comment: If I understand you, that seems like a good idea. Pass the DBManager as an argument to the constructor for the TableManager?

Comment: @Handcre: see my answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider passing `manager` to `TableManager` as a constructor parameter, so that you can have two different implementations of a *database manager*: a concrete one and a mock one.

```
// These two classes have the same interface.
class ConcreteDBManager 
{
    auto numberOfTables()
    {
        auto connection = connectToRealDB();
        return connection.queryAs<int>("COUNT TABLES");
    }
};

class MockDBManager
{
    auto numberOfTables()
    {  
        return 5;
    }
};

template <typename TDatabaseManager>
class TableManager
{
    TDatabaseManager _manager;
    TableManager(const TDatabaseManager& manager) 
        : _manager{manager} 
    {
    }

    auto numberOfTables()
    { 
        return _manager.numberOfTables(); 
    }
};
```

With this approach, you can test the functionality of the `TableManager` by providing a `MockDBManager` instance, so that you don't have to connect to the actual DB in your unit tests...

```
TEST(TableManager, RetrieveNumberOfTables)
{
    MockDBManager mockDBManager;
    TableManager<MockDBManager> tableManager(mockDBManager);
    EXPECT_EQ(5, tableManager.numberOfTables());
}
```

...but you can connect to the real DB in production code with the same `TableManager` interface:

```
void realProductionCode()
{
    ConcreteDBManager concreteDBManager;
    TableManager<ConcreteDBManager> tableManager(concreteDBManager);
    std::cout << tableManager.numberOfTables();
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that seems like a good idea. I'm going to do that. Is there a reason to have separate code for a mock db and the producton db? I planned to have the option to pass in the ip address, port number, and database name to the db manager, so wouldn't just specifying a localhost database to the actual db_manager be just as good as having a mock database implemented for testing?

Comment: @Handcre: if you do that you'll still rely on the state of the `localhost` machine. Unit tests are supposed to test the functionality of a specific class - if the class in question is `TableManager`, then you should test its behavior as independently from any other component as possible. Providing a mock gives you independence from any real database.

Comment: @Handcre There is absolutely reason to have code for a mock. It allows you to better unit test TableManager because you're not relying on how your DataBaseManager works. Additionally, unit tests will be faster because mock implementations usually greatly simplify the logic (e.g. returning `5` always for `numberOfTables`).

Comment: But how  do you test the functionality of the tablemanager then? From my understanding, unit testing of a method like, add_row(), would need to call the function and then check the database to make sure that row has been added?

Comment: I like the templating approach for your abstraction, and I think Alexandrescu would agree with you, too. However, I want to point out that it's a similarly common practice to instead abstract the functionality of a database into an interface class first, and then use inheritance to create the real `DataBaseManager`. The `TableManager` would then accept a pointer to the base class on construction. Same concept, slightly different paradigm.

Comment: @AndyG: yes, there definitely are advantages/disadvantages to both approaches. I personally don't like having to resort to pointers *(and potential dynamic allocation)* just to implement a mock, especially if I always know what type of manager I will use at compile-time. BTW, the compile-time equivalent of an "interface class" would be a  "concept-lite" :)